# Borel-Cantelli Lemma - is the measurability assumption necessary?

Tags: measure-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas, outer-measure

I've seen this version of the Borel-Cantelli Lemma in Stein and Shakarchi:

Let $(E_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a countable family of measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ satisfying $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}m(E_k) < \infty$$

Let $E$ be the set of $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $x\in E_k$ for infinitely many $k$.

Then $E$ is measurable and $m(E) = 0$.

Now in proving this it seems straightforward enough to show that the tail of the sequence goes to $0$, so for any $\varepsilon > 0$, choose $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{k=K}^\infty m(A_k) < \varepsilon$.

Now by definition of $E$, we have $E\subset \bigcup_{k=K}^{\infty}E_k$ so by monotonicity and subadditivity of the exterior measure, $m_*(E) \leq \sum_{k=K}^\infty m(A_k) < \varepsilon$ which proves the result.

But did we need the measurability assumption? I did not use it anywhere in this argument, so is that a mistake on my part or would this hold for a collection of sets which may not all be measurable, but the series of their exterior measures still converges.

Comment: measurability of $E_k$ is used in the formulation.

Comment: The measure $\mu$ is only defined for (Lebesgue) measurable sets.

Comment: @OliverDiaz But exterior measure is defined for all sets. Could we not just say that the series of exterior measures converges?

Comment: @JCAA But could we not formulate the statement more generally in terms of exterior measure?

Comment: You are right. If  $\sum m^{*}(E_k) <\infty$ then $E$ has measure $0$.

Comment: Yes, you can formulate this Borel-Cantelli lemma in terms of exterior measure. 

Let $(E_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a countable family of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ satisfying $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}m^*(E_k) < \infty$$

Let $E$ be the set of $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $x\in E_k$ for infinitely many $k$.

Then $E$ is Lebesgue measurable and $m(E) = 0$.

Comment: Of course you can but it won't be Borel-Cantelli any longer.

Comment: The proof goes as you suggested: for any $\varepsilon > 0$, choose $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{k=K}^\infty m(E_k) < \varepsilon$.

Now by definition of $E$, we have $E\subset \bigcup_{k=K}^{\infty}E_k$ so by monotonicity and subadditivity of the exterior measure, $$m^*(E) \leq 
m^* \left (   \bigcup_{k=K}^{\infty}E_k \right) \leq
\sum_{k=K}^\infty m^*(E_k) < \varepsilon$$ which proves the result.

Comment: @EG: the Lebesgue measure is already complete. so the exterior sets (ala Caratheodory) are already Lebesgue measurable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can formulate this Borel-Cantelli lemma in terms of exterior measure (this would be then a slight generalization of the Borel-Cantelli lemma).

Let $(E_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a countable family of subsets (not necessarily Lebesgue measurable subsets) of $\mathbb{R}^d$ satisfying $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}m^*(E_k) < \infty$$

Let $E$ be the set of $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $x\in E_k$ for infinitely many $k$.

Then $E$ is Lebesgue measurable and $m(E) = 0$.

**Proof**:
The proof goes as you suggested.

For any $\varepsilon > 0$, choose $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{k=K}^\infty m^*(E_k) < \varepsilon$.

Now by definition of $E$, we have $E\subset \bigcup_{k=K}^{\infty}E_k$ so by monotonicity and subadditivity of the exterior measure, $$m^*(E) \leq 
m^* \left (   \bigcup_{k=K}^{\infty}E_k \right) \leq
\sum_{k=K}^\infty m^*(E_k) < \varepsilon$$ which proves the result.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for.